# In react native, how can you set an event handler that reacts when a user drags from outside to inside the element?

Tags: react-native

[Tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSawc.png)

Each of these red shapes is an svg and I want the user to be able to drag across all of them and change the color of each of them as their finger touches them. Using onResponderMove, I can have the event of only the first touched svg be called if you press and drag. How can I call the event handler of each tile as they are touched?

Thanks

```
<Col style={{backgroundColor: 'green',}}>
    {this.state.tileColors.map((tileColor, index) => {
        const style = {...this.styles.tile, backgroundColor: tileColor}
        const view =  <View
            key={index}
            style={style}
            onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}             
            onResponderStart={() => {
                const newTileColors = this.state.tileColors;
                newTileColors[index] = this.state.currentColor;
                this.setState(state => ({
                    tileColors: newTileColors
                }));
            }}
        ></View>
        return view
    })}
</Col>
```